# PHP regexp remove tags between [] marquers

Tags: php, regex

Say I have

```
$content = "some text [again < dummy1>< /dummy1> some te < dummy2>< /dummy2>< /dummy3>xt] keep theses < needkeeped>xxx< needkeeped>"
```

I want to remove All tags `< dummyx>` but, I want to do it only for tags witch are between `[` and `]` chars

Expected result would be

```
$content = "some text [again some text] keep theses `< needkeeped>xxx< needkeeped>"`
```

I tried

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $content)
```

But it removed all the tags

Comment: Will the bracketed sections ever be nested? e.g. `[...[...]...]`?

Comment: no : [] can't be between [] e.g [...[...]...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[[^\]]+\]/', function($matches){
    return preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $matches[0]);
}, $content);
```

First, find all square bracketed regions, then replace the tags within them.

http://ideone.com/wmyfXS

Comment: Or, `strip_tags()` could be used within the callback

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
'/<[^>]*>(?=[^[\]]*\])/'
```

It's far from foolproof but it may be good enough.

It will only replace the tags when there is a `]` before a `[` ahead in the string.

Of course, it requires that there are no `<`, `>` , `[` or `]` in the string with a different usage.

Comment: full code:preg_replace('/<[^>]*>(?=[^[\]]*\])/', '$1', $content);

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho. Ah, I see. I guess you were saying that the `[` inside the `[]` should be escaped - it can be but it's not necessary.

Comment: @MikeM yes! I just tryed the regex in phpstorm, not in the php. :D

Comment: Right, sorry! full code:preg_replace('/<[^>]*>(?=[^[]]*])/', '', $content);